# Hide title field in a SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model, jslink

I'm creating a SharePoint list with JavaScript, now I want to hide the title field in the same process.

How can I achieve this?, I was trying to add a jslink, and in that document, hide the title field with JSRendering.

But I can't add a jslink programmatically, I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
var list = hostweb.get_lists().getByTitle("");
var view = list.get_views().getByTitle("");

var viewCreationInformation = new SP.ViewCreationInformation();
viewCreationInformation.set_title("");

var viewType = new SP.ViewType();
viewCreationInformation.set_viewTypeKind(viewType.html)
view = list.get_views().add(viewCreationInformation);
view.set_jsLink("~site/SiteAssets/test.js");

view.update();
currentContext.load(view);
currentContext.executeQueryAsync(onViewCreationSuccess, onViewCreationFailed);
```

Comment: To hide a field by javascript try this:
$("input[title='Title']").closest("tr").hide();

Comment: You can do by making Title column as hidden in List Item content type and then remove checkbox from Title column in view. In that way, it will neither appear in its newform/editform nor will display in its view.

Comment: I must do it programmatically, and in the same process as when im creating the list. Thats why NK SP will not work.

Answer (score 5):

The following example demonstrates how to control field visibility in List Forms using JSOM

```
function setFieldVisibility(listTitle,fieldName,properties,success,failure)
{
     var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current(); 
     var web = ctx.get_web(); 
     var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
     var field = list.get_fields().getByTitle(fieldName);
     field.setShowInDisplayForm(properties.ShowInDisplayForm);
     field.setShowInNewForm(properties.ShowInNewForm);
     field.setShowInEditForm(properties.ShowInEditForm);
     field.set_hidden(properties.Hidden);
     field.update();
     ctx.executeQueryAsync(success,failure);
}
```

Usage

```
var listTitle = 'Custom List';
var fieldName = 'Title';


var properties = {
      'ShowInDisplayForm': false,
      'ShowInNewForm': false,
      'ShowInEditForm': false,
      'Hidden': true
};
setFieldVisibility(listTitle,fieldName,properties,
   function () {
      console.log("Field visibility settings has been changed");
   },
   function(sender,args){
      console.log(args.get_message());
   }
);
```

Comment: Thank you, well the field does not hide in the view. But it hides itself in dispform, newform. But not in the view

Comment: You can't just modify the view settings and un-select the title field...? There is no requirement that the title field be displayed in a list view...